# Convert $_GET variables to $_POST and redirect page

Tags: php, post, header, get

I'm sending info through a link read in an email via $_GET (i.e. link in email is in form http://website.com?dogs=cats"). But I want the site URL to not have the appendages visible. So I've tried:

- Linking to a page which saves the $_GET in a hidden form fields, then automatically submits the form; problem is that the back button then leads back to this intermediary page
- Same as above, opening intermediary page in new tab, then having the form load another  new tab (_blank), and closes itself; works fine, except in IE these are windows, which are annoying

I'm considering saving the $_GET results in a cookie, then redirecting the page with a header(), then extracting data and expiring the cookie.

Is there an easier way that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about starting a session and storing them to the $_SESSION variables?

Comment: Can't believe I forgot about using a session. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample implementation of how you can make a hidden arguments on links. This sets a custom handler on the links which will copy hidden argument into the form and send it through post request. It is not a substitute to the session, but it can have it's own uses.

```
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
   <input id="dogs" type=hidden name="dogs">
</form>

<a href="otherpage.php" data-dogs="cats">Sample link</a>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('a').click(function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
            $('#dogs').val($(this).attr('data-dogs'));
            $('#form').attr('action',$(this).attr('href')).submit();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks romaninsh. The problem with using any JavaScript at all was that the back button of the next page would lead to this intermediary page instead of back to the email.

Comment: Yeah. It also have a nasty habit of asking to re-submit POST data. But I thought i'd add this trick.